# Code Difference

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I've just been visiting code review lately and I've realized what I'm doing is opening two browser windows, putting them side by side to compare my code with the answered code.

What I've realized from doing this is it might be helpful for codereview to have a special Code Diff function which puts codes side by side with answers, especially because this is a code review website so we can expect to have some alike code, and going up and down is dizzying.

Probably not possible, but worth to try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers should be **code reviews**, not just unexplained walls of code with tiny, hard-to-find changes.

So the real solution is to write good answers and edit, downvote and delete answers that do not contain sufficient explanation. This feature request is therefore declined.

Answer (score 1):

Neat request, and would be extremely helpful with large code snippets.

Something I use to compare code of my own and fits the description of the feature request is [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) ([source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/meld/)).  I think a feature comparable to that would be a nice addition to this site.

Answer (score 1):

As someone new to the site and fairly new to programming, such a side by side comparison would be IMMENSELY useful. Being able to see the differences in a more dynamic fashion would be a great learning tool!

Answer (score 0):

As long as this website is in beta I don't think any such addition will take place. But this doesn't mean we cannot see the differences by using other ways. I googled "online diff tools" and found [this quickdiff](http://www.quickdiff.com/) and [this diffchecker](http://www.diffchecker.com/diff). There are others also. It might be helpful to put some online tool(s) in the FAQ.